# Which is correct when referring to stroke count: 畫 or 劃?

Tags: character-identification

In the context of the audio on the page at http://stroke-order.learningweb.moe.edu.tw/characterQueryResult.do?word=%E7%95%AB which reads out 共十二畫/劃, which is more correct when referring to stroke count: 畫 or 劃?

It seems that 畫 and 劃 are equivalent according to Yabla's Chinese English Pinyin Dictionary when looking up the term "筆劃"¹, but the more-complex 劃 character provides more accurate results when run through Google Translate. 畫 gets translated as "painting". On the other hand, Google Translate seems to indicate the wrong tone (tone 2) when using 劃.

¹https://chinese.yabla.com/chinese-english-pinyin-dictionary.php?define=%E7%AD%86%E5%8A%83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *[劃](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/1469/)*
>
> *[4] [n] stroke (of a Chinese character*)

~

> *[畫](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/469/)*
>
> *[3] [n] stroke of a Chinese character*

For the meaning of 'pen stoke', it can be either. However, I prefer 劃.

When 劃 is used as a noun, it can only mean 'stroke'. meanwhile when 畫 is used as a noun, it means 'drawing' primarily.

Comment: Thanks. That makes things a bit clearer. Looks like I'll be going with 劃.